# Drupal 7 - Video Contest Website

Tags: 7

I'm new to drupal and I'm trying to create a video contest website. Each contest will have a time limit (Say 1 month). I need the following basic functionality.

1. Disable upload function after the contest ends.
2. People can vote during the contest but the total rating should be revealed only after the contest ends.

Is there a module for that purpose ? Or should I create a custom module?

Sorry if this is a silly question. I searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do this with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, which includes a Rules Scheduler submodule.  ([Node One tutorial on Rules Scheduler](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/introducing-rules-scheduler))
2. You can use [Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) for voting.  To hide the votes, you should be able to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).

These are very general suggestions but it sounds like you're in the very early stages of your planning; if you have specific questions, you're welcome to post those later.  Basically, you should be able to use existing, well-tested modules for what you're trying to do, although you may need to customize them from time to time to match your specific use case.  It's generally not worth your time to write modules from scratch, except as a learning exercise.